# Unique row combinations from duplicated columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has two columns. Column A repeats in Column b which is the primary key for several other tables. I need to find Where column A exists in column b more than 1 time.

I am using SQL2008

```
Table
Col A           Col B
0842311459      91
0884113434      91
9780842311458   91
9780884113430   91
9780842311458   95
9780884113430   95
0842359397      105
9780842359399   105
0687192706      135
9780687192700   135
```

I would like the output to be just the duplicate data either:

```
Col A         Col B
9780842311458   91
9780884113430   91
9780842311458   95
9780884113430   95
```

or

```
Col A           Col B
9780842311458   91 95
9780884113430   91 95
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `EXISTS`:

```
select t.cola, t.colb
from tablename t
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename
  where cola = t.cola and colb <> t.colb
)
```

For the 2nd version of your results do a self join:

```
select t.cola, concat(t.colb, ' ', tt.colb) colb
from tablename t inner join tablename tt 
on tt.cola = t.cola and tt.colb > t.colb
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9eb9ebe168a28ff7372377338cad146f).
Results:

```
> cola          | colb
> :------------ | :---
> 9780842311458 | 91  
> 9780884113430 | 91  
> 9780842311458 | 95  
> 9780884113430 | 95
```

and

```
> cola          | colb 
> :------------ | :----
> 9780842311458 | 91 95
> 9780884113430 | 91 95
```

Comment: Thank You all for these great options. I am really appreciative. I will test some of these out and play around. I really like the one using the self join.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE
    @TestData TABLE
    (
        ColA VARCHAR(20),
        ColB INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '0842311459', 91
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '0884113434', 91
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '9780842311458', 91
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '9780884113430 ', 91
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '9780842311458', 95
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '9780884113430', 95
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '0842359397', 105
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '9780842359399', 105
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '0687192706', 135
);
INSERT INTO @TestData
VALUES
(
    '9780687192700', 135
);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    @TestData
WHERE
    ColA IN
    (
        SELECT
            ColA
        FROM
            @TestData
        GROUP BY
            ColA
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    );
```

#### Result

```
9780842311458   91
9780884113430   91
9780842311458   95
9780884113430   95
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd5092392eb14ed436daec6c075c143e)

Answer (score 0):

you could use cte to get the same output

```
    create table #Table
    ( 
        ColA    varchar(100),   
        ColB    int
    )

    insert into #Table values ('0842311459'      ,91)
    insert into #Table values ('0884113434'      ,91)
    insert into #Table values ('9780842311458'   ,91)
    insert into #Table values ('9780884113430'   ,91)
    insert into #Table values ('9780842311458'   ,95)
    insert into #Table values ('9780884113430'   ,95)
    insert into #Table values ('0842359397'      ,10)
    insert into #Table values ('9780842359399'   ,10)
    insert into #Table values ('0687192706'      ,13)
    insert into #Table values ('9780687192700'   ,13)
```

first query

```
    ; with cte_first as (
    select  * 
    from    #Table
    )
    select  a.ColA, a.ColB
    from    cte_first a
    join    #Table b
            on a.ColA = b.ColA 
            and a.ColB <> b.ColB
```

second query

```
    ; with cte_first as (
    select  * 
    from    #Table
    )
    select  a.ColA, concat(a.colb, ' ', b.colb) colb
    from    cte_first a
    join    #Table b
            on a.ColA = b.ColA 
            and a.ColB > b.ColB
```

first output

```
    ColA            ColB
    --------------- ------
    9780842311458   95
    9780884113430   95
    9780842311458   91
    9780884113430   91
```

second output

```
    ColA            colb
    --------------- ------
    9780842311458   95 91
    9780884113430   95 91
```